# Unresponsive application after launched with JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I'm looking into the JNLP stuff and I decided to try to run a small application that I made with JNLP. I created a simple java program and the jnlp file. I upload both the jar file and the jnlp file to my apache server, along with an html file to display the Launch button. This is the jnlp file (I'm not 100% sure if it's correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="example.jnlp">
  <information>
      <title>Example</title>
      <vendor>Dev</vendor>
  </information>
  <resources>
      <!-- Application Resources -->
      <j2se version="1.6+"
            href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
      <jar href="Example.jar" main="true" />

  </resources>
  <application-desc name="Example"
       main-class="main.Example"
       width="600"
       height="600">
   </application-desc>
   <update check="background"/>
  </jnlp>
```

The following is my html file on my apache server:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
      // using JavaScript to get location of JNLP file relative to HTML page
      var dir = location.href.substring(0, location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
      var url = dir + "example.jnlp";
  document.alert(dir);
      deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(url, '1.6.0');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when I click the Launch button it asks if I want to run example.jnlp. Then after a bit the application just opens up but when I click any the buttons they do nothing. It's as if the GUI is showing but all over the under lying logic is not there. Any idea what may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> ..This is the jnlp file (I'm not 100% sure if it's correct): ..

It is not 100% correct.  Check it using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).  Of most concern is the HREF of "examp.jnlp", which does not seem to match the actual name.

> ..The following is my html ..

Which is also over complicated, and quite probably invalid, though I doubt that is the problem here.  For the moment, launch the JNLP from a plain old HTML link.  I am guessing you are testing from a machine running 1.6+ Java, so the deployJava.js is not necessary at this stage.

> ..after a bit the application just opens up but when I click any the buttons they do nothing. It's as if the GUI is showing but all over the under lying logic is not there. Any idea what may be the issue?

Without code it is a little hard to say.  But some preliminary questions are:

1. Does the code [swallow
   exceptions](http://pscode.org/javafaq.html#stacktrace) at any stage?  (If
   so, fix that immediately!)
2. What is reported in the Java Console when the application launches?  When debugging, it is essential to ensure the console pops open for every launch of a Java applet or JWS app.  Console visibility is configured via the [Java Control Panel](http://pscode.org/player.jnlp).